# invoking angular 2 ionic 2 app from another native app

Tags: angular, ionic2

we are having an app built using a mobile framework called MAF. we have another app built using angular 2/ionic 2. We want to launch this ng2/ionice 2 app from the app built using MAF.

For standard apps like instagram, facebook you can register a custom schema url like fb:// in your xcode. So the question is what do i do for my angular2 app which i will be using as custom schema to launch from MAF app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer here https://css-tricks.com/create-url-scheme/
all i did is just went to xcode version and added the custom url scheme

Comment: Please add the most relevant parts of the link in the answer, so if the link changes other SO users can still find how to do this.